# What happen to an event failure in a state machine?

Tags: state-machine, spring-statemachine

We just start a new project. People who started the project was not aware that it is a state machine application. After having a look at those states, I am wondering what happen to an event failure. Take t[his online shopping application state machine sample](http://blog.mimacom.com/introducing-spring-state-machine/), what if the deliver event or payment received event fails? Are abandon, failed, or retry part of states?

Answer (score 2):

When an event doesn't occur, through failure or otherwise, nothing happens.
In order to detect & handle this, time outs can be introduced to create a state transition that can then in turn be a corrective action (retry, etc).

Comment: is there an example somewhere on the web of this time-out based corrective-action state transition we can look at?

Comment: Sure. It's not a special state transition, you just label it as a time out based one.  Here's one adding that has TCP timeouts in it http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~agupta/cs340/project2/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf